# How to destroy or close a GTK window in another thread?

Tags: gtk

ENV: Ubuntu 14.04 + GTK 3.10.8 by c

My app is a remote desktop client. In main loop, a GTK window is created and displayed as an loading window with a progress bar in the center. When another thread connects to the remote server, it will hide or close or destroy the loading window and create a main window. My question is how to notify main thread to end the loading window?

Answer (score 1):

Use [`g_idle_add`](https://developer.gnome.org/glib/stable/glib-The-Main-Event-Loop.html#g-idle-add) to register a callback. Use the `data` field to pass a value saying what you want to do with the window (hide, close, destroy + create). The callback will be called from the main thread, the one used by GTK+, and you can manipulate the window safely from there.